# Trying to Retrieve values from PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

This is what I am trying. I am trying to call a function trial with retrieves a value from a PHP for values 1 to 29 and display the result in text input boxes named T1, T2...T29.

```
function calculate() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
        trial(i);
    }
}

function trial(i) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('T' + i).value = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET", "MANAGER/manager.php?rownum=" + i, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    return;
}
```

It is not working. Could you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Do you have your complete page to show all content to show where is the bug ?

Comment: "It is not working" doesnt means a error.Post the error you aare getting

Comment: There is a thing called jquery....

Comment: @Sam There is also a thing called common sense...

Comment: I double if `calculate()` is iterating properly. check the values, first using `console.log(i)`

Comment: @Deepu: Actually the value that is being returned by the PHP is not reflecting in the textboxes.

Comment: @phpNoOb: you are right. When I put an alert(i) in the beginning of trial it displays all the values from 1-29. But when I put alert(i+" - "+xmlhttp.responseText) just before document.getElementById('T'+i).value=xmlhttp.responseText all the values for i are not displayed, and those that are, seems random...

Comment: That means you are setting the value by document.getElementById('T'+i).value=xmlhttp.responseText;
So check  whether you are getting any value in xmlhttp.responseText by console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: Update: It works fine if I call trial once with out using loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are declaring the variable `xmlhttp` globally, so you are overwriting the callbacks and everything on each iteration.  Use the `var` keyword to make it local.